# How can I view a summary(average time of individual services) of all traces over zipkin containing 3 services(with node js)?

Tags: node.js, zipkin, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

I have a node js application which includes 3 API calls (3 services). I am sending the traces to zipkin UI. There I can view individual traces and time spans of particular services. But I want to view the average time of any of the 3 services over a particular time period. How to do that? I have attached some of the screenshots of zipkin UI.

[Zipkin UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wggLN.png)

[Showing of a individual trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZnBH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.